# GCP - How to register multiple Windows OS to kms.windows.googlecloud.com on a very secure VPC?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On Google Cloud Platform, how can I register/validate my Microsoft Windows machines, in a walled VPC?

For security reasons:
-Every connection goes through a proxy;
-Every Windows machine is not allowed to have an external IP address;

For money reasons:
-No Windows KMS relay server.

I read:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/getting-support-for-windows-instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, an external IP address is required to activate a Windows instance with Google’s KMS servers. You cannot turn off the external IP for a Windows VM  on Google Compute Engine as it requires re-activation every 30 days, however, Google is actively working on a fix to address this issue and to make it so you can activate against VMs with internal IP only.

For the interim, if you wish to restrict outbound communication you can set up egress firewall rules as follows:

1. Create a deny egress firewall rule for the IP range `0.0.0.0/0` on all ports
2. Create an allow egress rule to the IP `173.255.119.204` and the port `tcp:1688`. This will allow the VM to talk to the KMS Servers.

The allow rule should have a higher priority ( i.e. a lower number) than deny rule.

As mentioned earlier, there's a feature request to that is still in development and being tested internally. Unfortunately, there's no ETA at this time.

That being said, I would recommend that you follow the [Google Cloud Platform Blog page](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/), so you are aware once the feature is released, or use the above-provided workaround.

Finally, should you decide to continue using Windows OS without activation, keep in mind that the following may occur as per Microsoft Product Activation article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Product_Activation#After_grace_period)

Windows Server 2016 has a 30-day grace period and if not activated, the operating system may go into what is called Reduced Functional mode which means that certain functionality will be disabled, you may also see a watermark showing the edition of Windows as not activated.

Access to all Windows Updates with confidence that your Windows software has the latest security and reliability enhancements may be removed.

You will be prompted every time you log in to Activate, as well as receive periodic prompts to activate your software.

I hope this information is helpful.